# Laughing somebody out of town/court/the room

Tags: etymology, expressions

I heard of this expression:

```
We were laughed out of the room
```

After googling for it, it seems there are 2 more variations to it:

```
laughing somebody out of town
laughing somebody out of court
```

I would like to know which one was the original.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that ["laugh out of court"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/laugh+out+of+court) is the original expression:

> Dismiss with ridicule or scorn, as in When he told them the old car could be repaired, they laughed him out of court . This expression, which originally referred to a case so laughable or trivial that a court of law would dismiss it, originated in ancient Roman times but has been used in English, without its former legal significance, since the late 1800s.

"Laugh out of town" and "laugh out of the room" are probably variations.